# Webapp2 request application/octet-stream file upload

Tags: python, file-upload, content-type, webapp2

I am trying to upload a file to s3 from a form via ajax. I am using fineuploader http://fineuploader.com/ on the client side and webapp2 on the server side. it sends the parameter as qqfile in the request and I can see the image data in the request headers but I have no idea how to get it back in browsers that do not use the multipart encoding.

This is how I was doing it in the standard html form post with multipart.

```
image = self.request.POST["image"]
```

this gives me the image name and the image file

currently I have only been able to get the image filename back not the data with

```
image = self.request.get_all('image')
[u'image_name.png']
```

when using the POST I get a warning about the content headers being application/octet-stream

```
<NoVars: Not an HTML form submission (Content-Type: application/octet-stream)>
```

How do I implement a BlobStoreHandler in webapp2 outside of GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using fineuploader http://fineuploader.com/ which sends a multipart encoded form to my handler endpoint.

inside the handler I could simply just reference the POST and then read the FieldStorage Object into a cStringIO object.

```
image = self.request.POST["qqfile"]
imgObj = cStringIO.StringIO(image.file.read())

# Connect to S3...
# create s3 Key 
key = bucket.new_key("%s" % uuid.uuid4());

# guess mimetype for headers
file_mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(image.filename)
if file_mime_type[0]:
   file_headers = {"Content-Type": "%s" % file_mime_type[0]}
else:
   file_headers = None

key.set_contents_from_string(imgObj.getvalue(), headers=file_headers)

key_str = key.key

#return JSON response with key and append to s3 url on front end.
```

note: qqfile is the parameter fineuploader uses.

I am faking the progress but that is ok for my use case no need for BlobStoreUploadHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Your question code is not very clear to me. But you can use an example.

Have a look at this article from Nick Johnson. He implements a dropbox service using app engine blobstore and Plupload in the client : http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-2

Comment: my question is how do I handle an octet-stream request with webapp2